# Cannot write accented chars (ex ã) in Java apps

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, java

The title says it all: I can't write accented characters in Java applications. For now I have tried Idea IDE's and Netbeans and none accepts them. Using other applications it works as supposed. Note that this is not a problem of text file encoding.

So if I write "compilação" it gets written "compilaçao".

My current keyboard layout is Portuguese. If I select "Portuguese (eliminate dead keys)", when I write the same word I get "compilaç~ao".

So what may be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that this is caused by ibus or some bug in it. I managed to fix it by clearing XMODIFIERS envvar, ie:

```
XMODIFIERS="" java -jar /path/to/app.jar
```

For now I'm using this only in two specific Java apps, but setting this using `export` in `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` should work as well.

Comment: I was having the same problem with PHPStorm: accents not showing

Comment: Now I'm having this problem in 19.10 and this solution works.